# automated testing of epos systems

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have just started working for a new team - who currently test retail applications such as EPoS (end point of sale - tills). This is all currently done manually and I would like to start the process of automating this. I am putting together a business case to build some virtual tills which should be the first step in automating.  I would like to use Selenium Webdriver and wondered if anyone has any experience in anything like this? If there are any problems I'm going to encounter a heads up would be nice. 
Any advice?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on what language your systems are built in, what technologies are behind it etc?

Comment: That's where it gets a little confusing, I'm not 100% sure at the moment, as this is a 3rd party application. Are there various tools depending on the language/technologies?

Comment: Webdriver will only be useful to you if the epos is a web application.